# Using opencv and python on the pi 2 with IDLE

Tags: python, opencv, ide, raspberry-pi, python-idle

I wanted to write a few scripts for image processing using opencv which I would run in IDLE on the pi 2. I have installed opencv using a virtual environment. Everything works well in terminal and to run cv I simply use `workon cv` to enter the virtual environment the in python I can run `import cv2`.

How can I use `import cv2` in IDLE? Or maybe I should say, how can I use `workon cv2` in IDLE?

Also, I will be writing a lot of scripts over the summer all regarding image processing and what not, what should I use instead of IDLE (or maybe IDLE is perfect)? I am a novice python programmer, in case you haven't noticed :)

Comment: What problem are you solving by using a virtual environment? Is it worth the extra problems that come with venvs?  `workon xyz` is not a python statement, so you cannot use it in any python program, whether run from Idle or not.